# Comma separated agument evaluation

Tags: python

What is the meaning of the following expression:

```
assert "PASS" == res, msg
```

Which argument is being evaluated here?

Comment: You can guess it. You evaluate the boolean value (i.e. result of comparison operator), and if it's `False`, you terminate with an error and show `msg` error message

Comment: This expression can't be truth, btw.

Comment: @OlvinRoght of course it can, `res` just needs to have the value `"PASS"`.

Comment: @Masklinn, oh, you're right, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

The `assert` keyword is used when debugging the code.

This keyword test a condition (which is the first argument), if the condition returns false the program will give an `AssertionError`, you can write the `AssertionError` message (which is the second argument, separated with `,`).

Ex:

```
password = "hello"

assert password == "goodbye", "Access Denied"
```

output of the above code is:

`AssertionError: Access Denied`

Comment: Also your assertion makes no sense. You assert that the value is `goodbye` and print that it should be `hello` if it wasn't `goodbye`. I mean, thee password actually ***is*** hello and your message says it should be hello